# Ruby server logging a socket's request thrice

Tags: ruby, sockets

I am writing a simple server in Ruby in order to understand the Socket module. Here is my code:

```
require 'socket'
s = TCPServer.new(3939)

loop do
  c = s.accept
  STDERR.puts c.gets
  c.close
end
```

I simply want to print the request to the server console before closing the socket. Why does it print the request thrice, instead of just once?

Answer (score 0):

If I curl that code

```
$ curl localhost:3939
```

I get an empty reply

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

and a single GET request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```